# Installing angular packages from github fails

Tags: git, github, npm, proxy, windows-10

I just wanted to run`npm install angular-ui-router` from Visual Studio Code terminal,
but it fails. I use Windows 10 and somewhere here on Stackoverflow I read that the problem might be that I use an incompatible git version (2.19.whatever) so I upgraded my git to `git version 2.21.0.rc0.windows.1`. It still does not work. Below is the stacktrace I get:

```
npm ERR! Error while executing:npm ERR! C:\Users\pe\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\cmd\git.EXE ls-remote -h -t git://github.com/nmccready/google-maps-utility-library-v3-markerwithlabel.git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
npm ERR! github.com[0: 140.82.118.3]: errno=No such file or directory
npm ERR! github.com[1: 140.82.118.4]: errno=No such file or directory
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! exited with error code: 128

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\pe\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-02-13T10_41_56_811Z-debug.log
```

even `npm install -g npm` fails.

```
npm install -g npm
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/npm failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:443
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\pe\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-02-13T10_55_40_391Z-debug.log
```

I guess have no proxy-related issues(i.e. I set the proxies and get a meaningful value for 'npm get http-proxy' and npm get https-proxy').
Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is important to set proxies like this:

```
npm config set https-proxy http://host:port
npm config set proxy http://host:port
```

It is also important to put the following at the end of .gitconfig

```
[url "https://"]
    insteadOf = git://
[url "https://github.com"]
    insteadOf = git@github.com
```

This is however not enough if you happened to be on Windows 10. 
*Turns out (on Windows) `npm` will try to grab the `.gitconfig` file from user homedir (by default `c:\Users\[username]\.gitconfig`) and will ignore the global config / personal config if placed in a different location. Copying the global config file to above mentioned location fixed the issue for me.*

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-cli/issues/352

Answer (score 0):

You need to set npm config first

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Then you can do `npm install` or install any other packages.

Comment: sadly it does not seem to be helping

Comment: git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git:// or  make git config --global url

Answer (score 0):

I think *setting the proxies on your end may be contributing to the issue*, are you behind a corporate firewall and need a tunnel through a proxy or are you working from your personal machine?

Maybe you could try the following to see if it resolves your issue:

1. Unset your npm proxies:

   `npm config rm proxy
    npm config rm https-proxy`
2. Set your npm registry to point to npmjs without the need for ssl:

   npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
3. Install Angular Router again:

   `npm i angular-ui-router`

Hopefully that helps!